# Bitwise AND XOR on conditional statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to understand this snippet

```
for (; game->boxes_left > 0; game->turns++)
      {
      if ( (game->turns & 1) ^ game->computer_first )
         game->human_move();
      else
         game->computer_move();
      }
```

as inf `game->turns` is an integer, and it has increasing value , and `game->comp_first` is a boolean, Will anyone please tell me how `if ( (game->turns & 1) ^ game->computer_first )` return it's 1 (true) or 0 (false) ?
because what I understand `&` is bitwise operator and when `turns & 1` it will always return 0 , as `turns` is an increasing value, what is the function of `(game->turns & 1)` in this if statement? is there any way to write this snippet in java. Thanks in advance

Comment: Converting this to Java is a trivial task what have you tried? It seems like you have lots of questions surrounding Bitwise statement I suggest you do some research on how they work then actually accept soem of your question's answers. **This seems like a simple odd/even check based on who went first.**

Comment: sorry, about this question I did stupid mistake when calculate the bit wise, and about my bitwise questions, I still lost somewhere , because I read sometime when  applying bitwise on some objects it will result an object, meanwhile what I understand bitwise is a bit operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `game->turns` goes through consecutive values, its last bits switches between 0 and 1 on each iteration. As the result, `game->turns & 1` goes between 0 and 1 as well. XOR-ing the result with a bool gives you the same value if bool is false, and an inverted value if bool is true.

```
game->turns   Last bit   XOR 0    XOR 1
-----------   --------   -----    -----
          0          0       0        1
          1          1       1        0
          2          0       0        1
          3          1       1        0
          4          0       0        1
          5          1       1        0
```

Note how the sequence goes 0-1-0-1-0-1 when `game->computer_first` is `false`, and 1-0-1-0-1-0 when `game->computer_first` is `true`.

To convert this snippet to Java, compare the result of `game.turns & 1` with `)`:

```
if (((game.turns & 1) != 0) ^ game->computer_first) ...
```

Comment: owh ok ..ok get it now, just realize i made stupid mistake when apply AND operator, I didn't put 0 infront of `1`, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

game->turns & 1 will return true for every value of game->turns that is odd. E.g.:

```
turns= 0x00001111
one=   0x00000001
result=0x00000001
```

because the rightmost bit is "1" for both values. If computer_first is also "1", e.g. true, the if statement will return false, because 1 ^ 1 = 0.

Seems like a rather roundabout way of doing things though, if you ask me. Whats wrong with `if (game->turns % 2) != game->computer_first` ?

Comment: "Whats wrong with `if (game->turns % 2) != 0`?" It should be `if (game->turns % 2) != game->computer_first`, otherwise your sequence will go 0-1-0-1-0-1 regardless of who goes first.

Comment: +1 Now it looks good :) As far as "what's wrong" goes, it's certainly a matter of preference: I've seen people coding it both ways. These accustomed to coding in assembly usually prefer `(x & 1) ^ y` while others preferred the `%2`. In the end, it does not matter, because optimizing compiler will make roughly the same code for both cases.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. I don't have a strong assembly background so %2 seems more readable to me, but thats just an opinion of course :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, this code is based on the fact that as you increment a number, the least significant bit of its binary representation alternates between on and off.

IMO, the lack of readability is largely a symptom of a larger problem: the logic of the code isn't really the best. I think I'd do things just a bit differently. This is one of the rare cases where a couple of pointers to member functions really make sense and simplify the code quite a bit.

Since I don't know the actual type, I'm going to assume that `game` is a pointer to an object of type `Game`. From there, it's a fairly simple matter of defining pointers to the member functions for the first and second player, then writing a loop that consists of a pair of moves instead of a single move (or, depending on your viewpoint, really more like one complete move per iteration).

```
typedef void (Game::*pmf)();

pmf first_player = &Game::human_move;
pmf second_player = &Game::computer_move;

if (game->comp_first)
    std::swap(first_player, second_player);

for ( ; game->boxes_left > 0; game->turns+=2) {
    game->*first_player();
    game->*second_player();
}
```

Unfortunately, while this makes your code much cleaner and simpler, it also makes it quite a bit more difficult to convert to Java -- Java doesn't have a direct analog to C++'s pointer to a member function. The usual substitute is to define an interface, and then an anonymous class implementing that interface. Before you've done all that, it's probably simpler to start with something that has a little code duplication:

```
if (game->comp_first)
    for (; game->boxes_left > 0; game->turns+=2) {
        game->computer_move();
        game->player_move();
    }
else
    for (; game->boxes_left > 0; game->turns+=2) {
        game->player_move();
        game->computer_move();
    }
```

...and since this code doesn't use any advanced features, converting it to a lower-level language like Java should be fairly trivial. It seems obvious to me that using the pointers to member functions gives the cleanest result, *but* I still think this last version is quite a bit cleaner than what you started with.

I suppose I should add one more detail. Depending on the situation, it's possible that you may have to exit the loop after only one player has made a move. If that's possible for whatever game you're implementing, you'd change the two lines like this:

```
game->*first_player();
game->*second_player();
```

and instead have each of the move functions return a boolean indicating whether further play remains possible following that move, and your loop body would become something like:

```
if (game->*first_player())
    game->*second_player();
```

Comment: u need to check `boxes_left` after *each move*.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's the point of the last little bit -- but depending on the game, you may not need to do anything of the sort. A fair number a structured so if A goes first, then B will always get the last move.